# Blackboard exams not respecting eval options for schoice and mchoice

Tags: r, r-exams, blackboard

I have successfully created simple multiple choice blackboard exams using exams2blackboard() in the newest (github) version of the r exams package. However, including mchoice (multiple answer) questions and trying to enable partial credit and penalties is producing strange results that do not match my testing with exam_eval() and checkanswer().

for example, using the argument `eval= list(partial = TRUE, negative=FALSE, rule="true")` to exams2blackboard produces expected results with checkanswer:

```
ee <- exams_eval(partial=TRUE, negative=FALSE, rule="true")
ee$pointsum("11100", "11111")
# [1] 0.3333333
```

However, when I try the exam in blackboard the same set of answers (all true, when three of five should be correct), results in full points. Looking at the individual question settings in the imported test, it appears that some values are not set correctly. For example, with the above values in the exams2blackboard call, the test options look fine (eg allow negative penalties is on), but the individual questions show wrong values:

```
Allow Partial Credit [X]  ## This is set correctly
Allow Negative Scores for Incorrect Answers [ ] # This should be set!
Allow Negative Overall Score for the Question  [ ] # Not shown if above not set, but should be false.
```

Comment: Thanks for raising this issue. I can't check this myself but will ask my co-author Niels (Smits) to take a look. He's the main author of `exams2blackboard` but he's not on SO. I'll report here when I hear back from him.

Comment: Thanks! I also submitted an email bug report -- sorry to use both methods, I was not sure what was best.

Comment: One of the methods should typically suffice. I'm monitoring all the channels listed at: http://www.R-exams.org/contact/